# with 100% height and automatically scroll the bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good Afternoon person following'm doing my personal website and I am facing a problem when I put in the resolution below 640x960 resolution. 'm New to bootstrap 3, I'm learning now and I need your help.

Follow my code html:

```
<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo_natural_estudio.png" height="43" width="200" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li style="border-right:1px solid #36484c;"><a onclick="$('body').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:2000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});">Inicio</a></li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid #36484c;"><a onclick="$('#section-2').animatescroll({scrollSpeed:2000,easing:'easeOutBounce'});">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid #36484c;"><a href="#">Nosso Trabalhos</a></li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid #36484c;"><a href="#">O que Fazemos</a></li>
                <li style="border-right:1px solid #36484c;"><a href="#">Nosso Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <section class="container fill" id="section-1">

          <div class="row" id="meioConteudo">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h4>RESOLVEMOS SEU PROBLEMA!</h4>
                <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
                <h4>DESENVOLVIMENTO WEB CRIATIVO</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h1>Criação de Blogs e Sites</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h1>Layouts Responsivos</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h1>Design Gráfico</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>


    <section class="container" id="section-2">
        <div class="row" id="meioConteudo">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h4>RESOLVEMOS SEU PROBLEMA!</h4>
                <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
                <h4>DESENVOLVIMENTO WEB CRIATIVO</h4>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button" id="btnVeja">Veja Mais</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


<!-- Scripts funcionamento Jquery e Bootstrap -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/animatescroll.js"></script>
```

My code CSS

```
body, html{ margin:0; height: 100%;}
#menu{margin-top: 10px;}
.navbar-default{ background:#415357; text-align:center;}
.navbar-default .navabar-nav{cursor: pointer;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{ color:#FFF;  }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{ color:#0C0;}
.nav-pills > li > a{cursor: pointer;}
#meioConteudo{ text-align:center; padding-top:30px;}
#meioConteudo h4{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size:3.4em; font-weight:lighter;color:#3d4e51;}
#meioConteudo h2{font-family: 'Bitter', serif; font-size:6.8em; font-weight:bolder; margin-top:-30px; color:#3d4e51; margin-bottom:-20px;}
#btnVeja{ background:#3d4d51; color:#FFF; margin-top:50px;}
.nav-justified{ padding-top:15px;}
.nav-justified > li > a{ color:#FFF; }
.nav-justified > li > a:hover{ background:#304347;}
.container > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse{ margin:0;}
#section-1{padding-top: 50px;}
#section-2{background:rgb(233, 147, 26); padding-top: 50px;}
#section-3{background:rgb(22, 145, 190)}
#section-4{background:rgb(22, 107, 162)}
#section-5{background:rgb(27, 54, 71)}
#section-6{background:rgb(21, 40, 54);margin-bottom:-30px}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

link my site:

http://www.naturalestudio.com.br/bootstrap/

Help Help Help..

Answer (score 2):

The scrolling position doesn't seem right because of the height your header. The browser scrolls to the element but the header is lying on top. Try using padding as described on [AnimateScroll](http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/).